# what is the meaning of \usepackage{uorthesis} in Overleaf thesis's template

Tags: templates, overleaf

I downloaded and use one of the thesis templates which the link is below:
[enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template/bwkpcxzdysky)

There is a line:

```
\usepackage{uorthesis}  % Loads the LaTeX style package
```

But, i am not sure the meaning of this, I had googled but cannot find. Is it specific that uni's package?

I cancel it out, and the whole template does not work. I also want to change the front size also.

Comment: The URL in the link you provided contains this: `university-of-rochester-masters-slash-phd-thesis-template`. Does this tell you what `uor` in `uorthesis` means, and does it answer your question, "Is it specific that uni's package"? Or are you asking what `\usepackage` means? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico I want to ask: So `uorthesis` is University of rochester's thesis means. Can we change the format or even have a look what this package contains?

Comment: Can you access the file `uorthesis.sty`? (Sorry, I'm not on Overleaf and thus don't have the file.)

Comment: @Mico, yes, i can access and saw it, lots of package in `uorthesis.sty` file. What is the different between `main.tex` and `uorthesis.sty` file? I usually put my package in `main.tex` file.

Comment: Since you appear to have access to Overleaf, you should probably be posting these questions to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Or, read a basic introduction to LaTeX; you may want to search the internet for the 'not so short introduction to LaTeX', by Tobias Oetiker et al.

Comment: @Mico, thanks. I was thinking is Latex same too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not really specific to Overleaf; the same would happen whether you commented out the package and tried to typeset this template on Overleaf or on your own local TeX installation.

But, in terms of what the `uorthesis.sty` file does, checking the comments in the file you can see that:

```
% This defines everything necessary for a thesis
% Master's/PhD at UoR (or anywhere else).
%
% Do what you will with this package
%
```

So this package contains all the definitions necessary for the UoR thesis, so that is why the `main.tex` file has syntax errors without it. The contents of the main file are relying on the `uorthesis` package being loaded in the preamble.